# SQL Server: Cross-apply - record 0 for NULL results

Tags: sql-server, cross-apply

T1 is a table of company and their (multiple users), T2 is table of registered users. I counted, for each company in T1, how many of their users are in T2 but need c3 to appear in the result table with #regUser == 0:

T1:

```
company         user
c1               u1
c1               u2
c2               u2
c2               u3
c3               u4
c3               u1
```

T2:

```
user
u2
u3
```

So the resultant table should look like:

```
company         #regUser
c1                 1
c2                 2
c3                 0
```

With the following code I'm only getting the results for non-null companies:

```
select t1s.company, count(1)
from (select * from t1) t1s
  cross apply (select *
               from t2 t2s
               where t2s.reguser = t1s.[user]) t12s
group by t1s.company
```

Thanks

Comment: This query is overcomplicated. `from (select * from t1) t1s` is equivalent to just `from t1` for example. Why don't you try a simple left join between the two tables?

Comment: Why is this written with subqueries? This would simply be written as `select t1s.company, count(1)
from t1 t1s
     JOIN t2 t2s ON t2s.reguser = t1s.[user]
group by t1s.company`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just use left join

```
   select t1.company,count(t2.user)
     from t1 left join t2 on t1.user=t2.user
group by t1.company
```

the subquery is not necessary according to your requirement

but if you want to use `apply`  then you need like below query

```
select t1s.company, count(t12s.Users)
from (select * from t1) t1s
  outer apply (select Users
               from t2 t2s
               where t2s.Users = t1s.[Users]) t12s
group by t1s.company
```

output

```
company     #regUser
c1          1
c2          2
c3          0
```

[demolink](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=7ca4ea6242bf59c1e8f6d7f400887b10)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `LEFT JOIN` to get all the information of the left table with matching information from right table. By using a `GROUP BY` you can group the rows by company and get the `COUNT` of registered users for each company:

```
SELECT t1.company, COUNT(t2.[user]) AS regUser 
FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.[user] = t2.[user]
GROUP BY t1.company
ORDER BY t1.company ASC
```

You can also use the `CROSS APPLY` to solve this:

```
SELECT t1.company, SUM(CASE WHEN t1.[user] = t2.[user] THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS regUser 
FROM t1 CROSS APPLY t2
GROUP BY t1.company
ORDER BY t1.company ASC
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=22ee29d33ac642ceee0ff1ca0a8e8b9a)

Answer (score 1):

All you need is a left join :

```
select company,count(t2.[user])
from t1 left outer join t2 on t1.[user]=t2.[user]
group by company
```

The question's query is overcomplicated. For example, `from (select * from t1) t1s` is equivalent to `from t1 as t1s`.

Answer (score 0):

Just a `LEFT JOIN` with `SUM()`

```
CREATE TABLE T1(
  Company VARCHAR(20),
  Users VARCHAR(20)
);

CREATE TABLE T2(
  Users VARCHAR(20)
);

INSERT INTO T1 VALUES
('c1', 'u1'),
('c1', 'u2'),
('c2', 'u2'),
('c2', 'u3'),
('c3', 'u4'),
('c3', 'u1');

INSERT INTO T2 VALUES
('u2'),
('u3');

SELECT T1.Company,
       SUM(CASE WHEN T2.Users IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) Cnt
FROM T1 LEFT JOIN T2
ON T1.Users = T2.Users
GROUP BY T1.Company;
```

**Returns:**

```
+---------+-----+
| Company | Cnt |
+---------+-----+
| c1      |   1 |
| c2      |   2 |
| c3      |   0 |
+---------+-----+
```

**[Live Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=309082dead3261b5dc3ae529480a5034)**